# Youtube Playlists API pageInfo.totalResults and items are inconsistent

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The Youtube [Playlists API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) `playlistResponse.pageInfo.totalResults` and `playlistResponse.items` are inconsistent.

`pageInfo.totalResults` includes the “Liked videos” playlist, however, `items` does not include this playlist.

This issue is easier to observe if the number of playlists in the account is less than `maxResults`.

Call the [list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) method with the following request parameters:

- `maxResults: 50`
- `mine: true`

**Actual result:** `totalResults` includes the "Liked Videos" playlist.  For example, if the user has 7 playlists, `totalResults` is 8 as it includes “Liked videos”

**Expected result:** Either `totalResults` does not include the “Liked videos” playlist, or `items` does.

For example, I have 7 playlists, 8 including "Liked Videos". Here `totalResults` includes the "Liked Vidoes" playlist, whereas `items` does not.

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#playlistListResponse",
  "etag": "MRBqnBy-Y8RQ0TpqYmpqAE_05Lw",
  "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 8,
    "resultsPerPage": 7
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#playlist",
      "etag": "5-eWNGtmTPD4efCrIJvSCJwbYfE",
      "id": "ozfDHFjXSdWdBqXDbH0W"
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#playlist",
      "etag": "vAMuqE_49abzgSQTTSroegIi2xU",
      "id": "tglNJQrU86MyB7b3iqH5"
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#playlist",
      "etag": "D5Yv5VC-ZJ5wrJ6BV6Wbv0cSVXw",
      "id": "6zz7DncBpOw8Uzx0hYeV"
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#playlist",
      "etag": "OyI6XYGqAITCIBIgNZhKZh9akXs",
      "id": "Zbz6LcJlQYc2l3Wt73kr"
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#playlist",
      "etag": "Mexdqkd9YgKdOcMtRM8joax6Jfs",
      "id": "UjcPmVI0zukbmnvWXiEi"
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#playlist",
      "etag": "Mexdqkd9YgKdOcMtRM8joax6Jfs",
      "id": "p6ocnzio8hKNKAe85m6m"
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#playlist",
      "etag": "Mexdqkd9YgKdOcMtRM8joax6Jfs",
      "id": "OXCW0pdVWeYLjPsXN1mA"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: For people having used YouTube Data API v3 it is well-known that we can't trust `totalResults` and `resultsPerPage`. Normally if you count items of your playlist with the YouTube interface items returned, the counts match. So for getting all elements of a playlist exceeding `maxResults` items, just based your algorithm on the existence and the change of `nextPageToken`

NB: I don't know whether or not there is an official comment about this unprecise values (`totalResults` and `resultsPerPage`) in YouTube Data API v3 documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.


The problem with using `items.length` as you suggest, is that it only gives me the items per page (the number of items in that response).  However, what I need is the total possible items in the playlist.


Interesting that you say `pageInfo.totalResults` can’t be trusted, do you have any examples?

Comment: I know that at least one of `totalResults` and `resultsPerPage` is "officially" approximative. I stopped looking for logics behind YouTube Data API v3. I am just giving people a way to get the data they are looking for. If you want the total possible items in the playlist you can get all items from the API and count them or if you don't want to spend too much of your data you can use a shell with for instance: `curl -s https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAYLIST_ID | grep -F '"stats":[{"runs":[{"text":"'`